# How to get Windows Photo Gallery?

Tags: windows-7, windows, photos, picasa, windows-photo-gallery

I currently use Picasa for managing photos in my windows 7 pc. But, I would like to switch from Picasa to something else and I think [Windows Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/photo-gallery) would be a good option. The problem is it comes with Windows Essentials which includes [other softs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/download-windows-essentials#wetabs=we2012)(Movie Maker, Photo Gallery, OneDrive, Family Safety, Mail, Writer) which I do not want(especially Movie Maker because it needs a graphics card).

So my question is, is there any way to get the Windows Photo Gallery alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful links:
[Download Windows Essentials 2012](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-live/photo-gallery)
[Windows Essentials 2012 Release Notes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/essentials-2012-release-notes)
[Install Windows Essentials Offline](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-live/essentials-install-offline-faq)

I am very glad to inform that Windows Photo Gallery is a nice piece of software for photo management. The feature of it which I like most is the picture editing tools, it allows you to change each parametre as you like, rather than one-click way in Picasa.
To answer my own question, you cannot install Photo Gallery alone(AFAIK), but along with movie maker. You may exclude the other utilities(OneDrive, Family Safety, Mail, Writer).

Answer (score 0):

Install the Windows Essentials and then uninstall them. At that time you can select which components to uninstall and which ones to keep. But if I remember right, Photo gallery and Movie Maker are 1 block tied together. The others are singular.

Btw - I don't think you need a graphics card for MM. A good on-board graphics should do.

Another really excellent photo managing program is this one:  http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm

Comment: I have a video card which have about 750MB graphics memory, will MM work with it?

Comment: It should, but you will only know for certain if you try it out.

Comment: @ whs Okay then, I shall give it a try and then share my feedback here.

Comment: You need at least DirectX 9.0c. You can check that as follows: type dxdiag into start/search and hit Enter. From there you can check it. With a halfway modern system you should have DirectX 11.0 which would be ample.